# How can I show all non-theme extensions installed in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have many themes installed in visual studio code. Now and then, I want to be able to look at all the other extensions (everything that is not a theme) so that I might disable one or two.

How can I do this? [The documentation shows how to use filters](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery), but I don't see any way to tell it to NOT show something.

This filter shows me all the installed themes:

```
@installed @category:themes
```

I've tried using ~ and ! and NOT in various places, just guessing there might be a feature implemented to understand something like that, but they don't work.

Comment: Still not there it seems. While you can do `@enabled -@category:"themes"` for some bizare reason it filters out some of the enabled themes (before - it shows 72, after minus 55). Its irritating as I want to do exactly the same as you. Show all enabled plugins EXCEPT for themes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a know issue, currently at the backlog waiting for development.

You can track it [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/49374).

This need has been raised [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/61798). Note in the last comment:

> #49374 is tracking the feature of having exclusion filters for your scenario of seeing non theme extensions.